# How to Get CORS to use HTTP 304 instead of HTTP 200 responses

Tags: rest, express, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-304

It is unclear whether my RESTful CORS responses are ever retrieved from the cache. They all had the **200** status code but never **304**; even though there is no change in the request, the response, and the `If-None-Match` and `Etag` headers.

The response headers are as follows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.acme.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Cookie, Origin
```

While the preflight requests are no longer invoked on a per-request basis, all other XHR calls are returning **200** HTTP response.

This problem only happens for cross-origin requests.

Edit:
Following is a redacted excerpt:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const server = express();
server
    .set( 'etag', 'strong' )
    .use( cors({
        credentials: true,
        maxAge: 86400,
        origin: 'http://www.acme.com'
    }) )
    .use(( req, res, next ) => {
        res.setHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' );
        res.setHeader( 'Pragma', 'no-cache' );
        res.setHeader( 'Vary', `Cookie, ${ res.get( 'Vary' ) }` );
        next();
    })
    ...
```

Comment: The Access-Control-Max_Age is already in the headers. As for the Cache-control header, `no-cache` is an abbreviation for `max-age=0, must-revalidate` which means "cache the response but always confirm with the server before using the cached response"

Comment: According to the definition of `no-cache` (thanks for that!), the client should send an `If-None-Match: <ETag>` header with every subsequent request. But this leads to a 304 response only if the server implements ETag handling. Is that the case? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Also, does the response contain an `ETag` header? Without that, the browser cannot send an `If-None-Match` header. Or does the response contain a `Last-Modified` header?

Comment: The client sends the If-None-Match: <Etag> on every request. The If_None_Match request header equals the Etag response header. The response header does not contain the Last-Modified header though.

Comment: Can you share the relevant server code that implements ETag handling?

Comment: Yes, I have now appended the snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269602) of Chrome.

When processing a conditional request where the response matches the ETag, express sets status 304 and returns an empty payload, see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2c47827053233e707536019a15499ccf5496dc9d/lib/response.js#L209-L218). You can verify this with

```
> curl -v -H "If-None-Match:..." http://server/path
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< ETag: "..."
```

This server behavior is independent of whether the request is cross-origin or not.

When the Chrome browser receives this response, it takes the payload from its cache and displays it in the network trace, together with status 304. *However*, in case of a cross-origin request, it displays status 200 instead. But this is an artifact of the browser alone, and has got nothing to do with the server.